# Transitioning from cement board to drywall on a corner -what options do I have?

Tags: drywall, cement-board, transition

In the diagram below I need to transition from cement board to drywall (on the edge marked with red)

Do I need anything special for this?
That outside corner will be covered in tiles as the surrounding walls
I am not sure if I need anything under the tiles like corner beading or similar
[image]

Comment: just use the regular corner product for drywall. (plastic corner reinforcement, or just tape)

Comment: yea this guy does not seem to use anything else -I just need to be able to miter the tiles like he does :-)) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5DF4neLhMm8